# Set MIME type for ".mjs" file loaded in WebView of vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a `vscode` extension that displays a webpage inside a `WebView`.

The webpage has a `<script>` tag with `type="module"` and is sourced through `vscode-resource` protocol. That JS module fails to load inside `WebView` with the following error:

"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "application/unknown". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

How can I set the MIME type for that resource?

Comment: Did you found how to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the server to send .mjs files as JavaScript MIME type

```
text/javascript
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my question, this is a `vscode` extension. There is no server to set the MIME type.